can't create new PosExplorer Object using Microsoft point of sales for .net
I'm trying to use Microsoft point of sales for .net 1.14.1 version and trying to use it's Cash drawer capabilities for my Windows form application. But when i'm trying to create PosExplorer new object it throws "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" Error. I installed Microsoft point of sales for .net 1.14.1 runtime for my pc as well but i couldn't find the issue in here. below i have mentioned the relevant code segment for this issue.
`PosExplorer explorer = new PosExplorer();
// Find the first connected cash drawer
DeviceCollection cashDrawerDevices = explorer.GetDevices(DeviceType.CashDrawer);
if (cashDrawerDevices.Count == 0)
{
MessageBox.Show("No cash drawer found.");
return;
}
DeviceInfo cashDrawerInfo = cashDrawerDevices[0];
// Claim the cash drawer
_cashDrawer = (CashDrawer)explorer.CreateInstance(cashDrawerInfo);
if (_cashDrawer == null)
{
MessageBox.Show("Failed to initialize cash drawer.");
return;
}
_cashDrawer.Open();`
Can you help me to understand the issue here?

Please add information about what kind of work you are doing in what kind of environment and configuration. To use a device with POS for.NET, the .NET service object or OPOS service object provided by the target hardware vendor must be installed, and properly set up and configured. Is the work performed according to the documentation provided by the vendor? Also, if you use a cash drawer, you don't have to create a program yourself; there is a sample application in the POS for.NET SDK, so you can try it and see if it works.
